# Join's query as datasource in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have datagridview with datasource of users table in sqlite where I can set a group of user and some additional info.
Users saves in one table, groups in another.
For get data of groups name I'm just using JOIN query. But datasource in datagridview not works with JOIN querys. There any way to resolve this problem?

***EDIT:***
There my sqlite datasource

```
        SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source=data;"));
        connection.Open();
        string usersString = "SELECT * FROM users";

        DS = new DataSet();
        DA = new SQLiteDataAdapter(usersString, connection);
        DA.Fill(DS);
        dataGridView.DataSource = DS.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        connection.Close();
```

Everything works good. I found solution but I don't know how it is use in my code.
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn has a DataSource property. So I guess it is need use like:

```
       groupsString = "SELECT * FROM groups";
       DS = new DataSet();
       DA = new SQLiteDataAdapter(usersString, connection);
       DA.Fill(DS);
       comboBoxColumn.DataSource = DS.Tables[0].DefaultView; // What need to write here?
       comboBoxColumn.ValueMember = "id";
       comboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "groupName";
```

Comment: Can you post some code please?

Comment: I would check your sql query by running it in SQLite as this is most likely the problem

Comment: I have added some code

Comment: What is your problem exactly? You have a `join` query in SQLite and you're not able to view it in datagrid?

Comment: I'm deleted JOIN in sqlite query because when it is working and I'm trying to update() data SQLite says that it's impossible because datasource sqlite not works with JOIN querys.

So. I have user field in datagridview. In each user field I have combo box for select "Group" of user. I saved groups in one table of sqlite, users in another table of sqlite. In groups tables I have only 2 field: "ID" and "groupName". In users table I have field "group" where I save ID of group.

Comment: Ok, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't get your question. I have only 2 sqlite query: "SELECT * FROM users" and "SELECT * FROM groups" as u can see.